# Umbraco error with the Content.ascx file

Tags: visual-studio, umbraco

I'm getting an error when I try to build my web project in VS2015:

```
Could not load type 'umbraco.cms.presentation.create.controls.content'
```

It's very limited what I can find on the internet about this issue.
This issue seems related to a file in the umbraco installation folders **Content.ascx**. Deleting the file seems to bring more errors with other files in the same folder.

Anyone knows how to solve this error?

Comment: What version umbraco

Comment: and how did you install it (nuget? other?)

Comment: Umbraco version 7.4.1 assembly: 1.0.5891.23238

Comment: It's a project which is already done by another developer, all I did basically is copy the project into my computer. I setup iis localhost server and database and everything seems working fine. All I get is this error when bulding the project...

Comment: If it's 7.1.4, it shouldn't be trying to load that particular control, as 7 uses the new Angular dialogs for content creation.

Comment: Are you aware of any customisations to the Umbraco code? I'd be inclined to blow away your umbraco files and pull them again from nuget

Comment: There is a new umbraco update 7.5.2, would it help if I install/update it on my current project through nuget? and would it ruin my current project or work?